# Do cyclists need liability insurance in Lithuania? And if so, where can I buy one?

Tags: insurance, bicycles, lithuania, vilnius

I plan to visit Vilnius and hire a bike for city tour. The safety guide says that the third party liability insurance is mandatory in order to use the service. How can I purchase this kind of insurance online or in local offices in Vilnius? Is it possible for non-resident? I'm just staying there for 2 days.

Comment: Will you have Travel Insurance for this visit?

Comment: @CMaster yes, but it does not include third party liability option. I am from Belarus, our companies does not provide this type of insurance for travelers abroad.

Comment: @YuriRudakov OK, interesting. My travel insurance from the UK normally includes ~£1million of liability cover (not specifically for cycling, but I can't see why it would be excluded)

Comment: @CMaster When I was cycling in England in 2013 I had additional insurance that included over 1 million euro of personal liability but it was expensive, it's not an option for 2 days travel in Lithuania

Comment: Edited the question to make it a bit more broad, as it's possible that the safety guide was wrong.

Comment: Did you look into whether bike rental companies offer insurance?  Or is the safety guide from a rental company, saying "if you want to rent from us you must first have insurance"?

Comment: @phoog this is the guide from cyclocity.lt itself. I asked them and they replied that they "... don’t have any contracts with insurance companies and bicycle drivers can be insured by themselves or not" and recommended one company, but I am unable to send an e-mail since the feedback form requires the lithuanian phone number

Comment: If you lived in the UK, you could join the CTC (aka Cycling UK), which provides liability insurance for cycling in most of the world. Don't know if there's anything similar where you are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify things beforehand, liability insurance is not generally needed for bicycling in Lithuania (to the best of my knowledge), but to use the services of Cyclocity Vilnius. [On their website it says](http://en.cyclocity.lt/Safety)

> **Your responsibility**
>   [...]
>   Make sure you have third party liability insurance, which is mandatory in order to use the service.

Liability insurance is generally very good to have so my first recommendation would be for you to get one in your home country or country of residence (you indicate Belarus) and make sure that the terms  & conditions also cover your travel to Vilnius.

Otherwise you could try to purchase a liability insurance just for travel. You will likely still be better off with offers from Belarus but you could also try with international providers. The first hit googling for "liability insurance for travel" gives me this (apparently American, but targeting internationally) [provider](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/news/personal-liability.php) (no affiliation), I am sure there are many more upon a more thorough search.

Alternatively, I found two other providers of bike rental in Vilnius (they also offer bike tours):

- [Velo Vilnius](http://velovilnius.lt/en/)
- [Velotakas](http://www.velotakas.lt/en/)

They do not mention need of a liability insurance but be aware that the system is different from Cyclocity (which is similar to Velib in Paris, i.e. you can drop and take bikes at/from several stations in town) and you rent a bike e.g. for the day.

Finally - though this is not recommended and only my assumption - I do not believe that Cyclocity checks that you do have liability insurance. I would not know how to prove mine, I do not carry around my contract when traveling. And if you do get in trouble, you are in double trouble.

Comment: Liability insurance seems like a huge overkill for cycling. The odds of causing enough damage to wipe out your bank account are astronomically low. For everything else you don't need insurance, you just pay out of pocket.

Comment: @JonathanReez How so? You can kill someone with a bike (or even without any specific device, which is why mts recommends having a generic liabiltiy insurance anyway), it does not happen often but can cost a lot, which is precisely why it makes sense to take a cheap insurance against that risk. Note that low odds are a *sine qua non* for insurance, otherwise it would be either too expensive (if the costs are high) or useless (as you could simply pay the costs out of pocket).

Comment: @Relaxed are there statistics on third-party damage by cyclists somewhere? I've heard of plenty cyclists killing (or seriously hurting) themselves, but never of someone seriously hurting another person. Besides, liability lawsuits in Europe don't work like they do in the US - the amounts awarded to victims are generally a lot lower.

Comment: @Relaxed in Czech Republic, for example, it's common to have a section in apartment rentals that says "liability insurance is mandatory", but most people don't get one. It's just a legalese way of getting rid of all responsibility, not something with a strong rationale.

Comment: @JonathanReez I have heard of a cyclist killing someone recently, I did not make that one up. Insurance companies certainly have statistics, and it is uncommon to be sure (that's why personal liability insurance is generally cheap and does not exclude cycling) but damages if you hurt someone else can be very high (maybe not US-high but still too high for most people to take the hit easily) so the rationale is quite simple to understand. That's why personal liability insurance is something many people have in some countries, not a huge overkill.